# How to redirect home page to /home in order for structure navigation to work as expected?

Tags: structure, navigation

My site lives at something like http://example.com/subdomain/ee. Visiting that site root displays the home page just like I want it to. However, I'm using Structure to output a main navigation like so:

{exp:structure:nav
   css_class="nav-main"
   current_class="active"
   max_depth="1"
}

This works great for the most part, except I have a Home link in the main navigation that is the home page, and it's only getting the "active" class if I'm //example.com/subdomain/ee/home, not if I'm at //example.com/subdomain/ee.

I'm relatively new to EE, so I suspect there may be a simple way to fix this. Is there a good way to still use structure to output the primary navigation and have it apply the active class to the "Home" link when on the site root? Is there a better way to approach this than what I'm doing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To make this work, in the entry for Home under the structure tab, set the Structure Page URL to "/"

Comment: Argh, so easy! I'd tried changing the regular URL title (in the Publish tab) to "/", but when I submitted that it reverted back to "home". I could've sworn I tried changing the structure page URL as well, but clearly I didn't since this worked perfectly. Thank you!